# Error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [time,value] even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

This is the query in the @Dao

```
@Query("select timeAndValueList from VehicalSpeed WHERE sessionId = :id AND signalName = :name")
fun getTimeAndValueList(id:Int, name:Int): List<TimeValueList>
```

This is the VehicaleSpeed class/entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "VehicalSpeed")    
data class SignalDetails(    
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var sessionId: Int,   
   val timeAndValueList:List<TimeValueList>     
)
```

And this is the POJO TimeValueList

```
data class TimeValueList(
   val time: Float,
   val value: Double
)
```

Comment: How do you save `SignalDetails` into your `Room`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `VehicalSpeed` table, there is no `signalName` column that you are trying to retrieve.

**Note:** It can't be able to insert the list directly into db. You should be using TypeConverter to do it. Check this [link](https://mobikul.com/insert-custom-list-and-get-that-list-in-room-database-using-typeconverter/) for TypeConverter